# Android Room migration failing due to finding null indices

Tags: android, android-room, database-migration

I'm trying to do a room migration and add a new table with an index, but it is failing.

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "ring" ,
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = BellScheduleRoom::class,
                         parentColumns = arrayOf("code"),
                         childColumns = arrayOf("bellScheduleCode"),
                         onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                         onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)],
    indices = [Index(value = ["bellScheduleCode"])])
data class RingRoom(
        @PrimaryKey
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id", defaultValue = "0")
        var id: Int = 0) {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "dayOfWeek", defaultValue = "0")
    var dayOfWeek: Int = 0
    @ColumnInfo(name = "timeStart", defaultValue = "")
    var timeStart: String = ""
    @ColumnInfo(name = "durationInSeconds", defaultValue = "0")
    var durationInSeconds: Int = 0
    @ColumnInfo(name = "repeats", defaultValue = "0")
    var repeats: Int = 0
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bellScheduleCode", defaultValue = "")
    var bellScheduleCode: String = ""

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Ring: \n \t id: $id\n \t dayOfWeek: $dayOfWeek\n \t timestart: $timeStart\n \t 
                durationInSeconds: $durationInSeconds\n \t repeats: $repeats"
    }

    constructor(id: Int, dayOfWeek: Int, timeStart: String, durationInSeconds: Int, repeats: Int, 
        bellScheduleCode: String): this(id){
        this.dayOfWeek= dayOfWeek
        this.timeStart = timeStart
        this.durationInSeconds = durationInSeconds
        this.repeats = repeats
        this.bellScheduleCode = bellScheduleCode
    }
}
```

Migration:

```
class Migration_1_2 : Migration(1, 2) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `bell_schedule` (`description` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `code` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '' , PRIMARY KEY(`code`))")
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `ring` (`dayOfWeek` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `timeStart` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `durationInSeconds` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `repeats` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `bellScheduleCode` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `id` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, PRIMARY KEY(`id`), FOREIGN KEY(`bellScheduleCode`) REFERENCES `bell_Schedule`(`code`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE )")

        database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX `index_ring_bellScheduleCode` ON `ring`(`bellScheduleCode`)")
    }
}
```

When running this migration test I get output that doesn't entirely make sense to me.

```
class TestMigration1to2 {

    private val TEST_DB = "migration-test"

    @Rule @JvmField
    val helper: MigrationTestHelper = MigrationTestHelper(
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
        DatabaseRoom::class.java.canonicalName,
        FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory()
    )

    @Test
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun migrate1To2() {
        var db = helper.createDatabase(TEST_DB, 1).apply {
            close()
        }
        db = helper.runMigrationsAndValidate(TEST_DB, 2, true, Migration_1_2())
    }
}
```

Expected(makes sense):

```
TableInfo{name='ring', columns={dayOfWeek=Column{name='dayOfWeek', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, repeats=Column{name='repeats', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='0'}, durationInSeconds=Column{name='durationInSeconds', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, timeStart=Column{name='timeStart', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, bellScheduleCode=Column{name='bellScheduleCode', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='bell_schedule', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[bellScheduleCode], referenceColumnNames=[code]}], indices=[]}
```

Found (here's my issue):

```
found: TableInfo{name='ring', columns={dayOfWeek=Column{name='dayOfWeek', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, repeats=Column{name='repeats', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='1'}, durationInSeconds=Column{name='durationInSeconds', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, timeStart=Column{name='timeStart', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, bellScheduleCode=Column{name='bellScheduleCode', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='bell_Schedule', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[bellScheduleCode], referenceColumnNames=[code]}], indices=null}
```

The part that is confusing me the most is the `indices=null` part. The found indices are always null no matter what I do. Even if I remove the index entirely the migration still fails because indices are null instead of []. Why is the migration finding null indices?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is months old, yesterday I've encountered the same problem, and the reason was that I forgot to disable foreign keys when running my migration. I was getting this referenceColumnNames=[null] for a foreign key relation.

Running
`PRAGMA foreign_keys=off;` 
Before migration and
`PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;` 
after it solved the issue. Seems like room was silently failing to assign foreign keys at migration time and then complained about that at runtime.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324780/migration-not-handled-properly-in-room