# Migration not handled properly in Room

Tags: android, sqlite, migration, android-room

I have one db table class where I did change related to indices. Previously indices was like :

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"jobNumber", "jobId"},
        unique = true)})
```

But I changed it to

```
@Entity(indices = {
        @Index(value = "jobNumber", unique = true), @Index(value = "jobId", unique = true)
})
```

But when I tried migration it's giving me issue like :

```
caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle Job
```

I need to go with second format only. I tried to add migration but seems not working. Here is my code :

```
 public static final Migration MIGRATION_4_5 = new Migration(4, 5) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        migrateJobTableForIndices(database);
    }
};

private static void migrateJobTableForIndices(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
    //create new table
    database.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE Job_new (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, jobId INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    "jobNumber TEXT)");

    database.execSQL("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_Job_new_jobNumber_jobId ON Job_new (jobNumber, jobId)");
    // Copy the data
    database.execSQL(
            "INSERT INTO Job_new (id, jobId, jobNumber) " +
                    "SELECT id, jobId, jobNumber " +
                    "FROM Job");
    // Remove the old table
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE Job");
    // Change the table name to the correct one
    database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Job_new RENAME TO Job");
}
```

Is there any way to add migration for updated indices format. Any reference is really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As `Room` generates index names. You could export the scheme to see what is happening. By adding the following to your build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Now for the migration.

Beforehand you have to turn the `foreign_keys` off:

```
database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;")
```

You have to drop the existing index. For example:

```
database.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `index_Job_jobNumber_jobId`")
```

Then I would suggest renaming the **old** table.

```
ALTER TABLE Job RENAME TO Job_old
```

Create the **new** table `Job`.

Then create the index, which you will find in the exported schema location. In this example, it is in your `$projectDir/schemas`. From the files there you could see and copy how `Room` creates the indexes and add the creation of these indexes after the table creation.

Migrate the data.

Drop the **old** table.

Turn the `foreign_keys` on:

```
database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;")
```

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help! :)